# How to group columns on SharePoint JSGrid

Tags: spgridview

I'm using SharePoint JSGrid on my custom ApplicationPage and I need to create a visualization like this:

```
             |      Group 1           |     Group 2            |
Column A     |  Column B  | Column C  |  Column D  | Column E  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
Row1 Value   | 000        | 111       |  2222      | 3333      |
Row2 Value   | 220        | 133       |  2222      | 3333      |
```

I can find anything that may allow creating the group of columns. Can you help me?

Comment: You tagged this with SPGridView but you're talking about JSGrid... can you clarify what you are using? Maybe a link?

Comment: Sorry, but at the moment I created the thread, there were no tags for JSGrid and my level does not allows me to create new tags.